# Не получается использовать 'org.json:json:20200518' в андроид

Tags: java, android

После подключения 'org.json:json:20200518' андроид продолжает использовать встроенную реализацию org.json
Пытался делать так:

```
implementation 'org.json:json:20200518'{
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

Но не получается выдает:

```
Could not find method org.json:json:20200518() for arguments 
[build_57h7kjwe5eon8mcqvvzin2rgz$_run_closure2$_closure9@11e86224] on object of type 
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
Open File
```

Comment: А почему вы решили, что Андроид перестанет это делать? Это можете перестать делать вы в своем коде, но никак не Андроид как таковой. Этот пакет встроен в его фреймворк.

Comment: я же указываю что хочу использовать один пакет вместо другого

Comment: Это вы Gradle указываете, а он не распоряжается встроенными в фреймворк пакетами. Только внешними, через него подключенными.

Comment: Боюсь, в вашем случае только так, через переименование пакета. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33803776/dont-use-androids-built-in-org-json